# how to apologize for a mistake in a file

Tags: email

My english is bad and I need to answer in english.
I was asking for a quotation and I realized the price was wrong after I sent the mail. 
How do I apologize? 
It is correct to say: sorry I corrected the file due to a mistake in the previous one.? or what else can I say?

Comment: The mail was for a client or a colleague? Anyways, you should send the erratum ASAP

Comment: For a customer.

Comment: Have you asked your boss how should you proceed with this?

Comment: she just told me to correct the quotation but i dont know how to say in the email.

Comment: Can I say this: I corrected the quotation due to a mistake in the previous one. ?

Comment: @SimonB - And also say you are sorry. We all make mistakes

Comment: @SimonB PLEASE, don't answer in comments. Post an answer instead so the Community can vote on it and so it is preserved for future and current users.

Answer (score 5):

please disregard previous quotation sent 01/01/2018, there was an error. Please find attached the correct quote. My apologies for any inconvenience.

Regards
Me

Comment: This is, at best quite awkwardly stated, because it is brusquely factual and apologetic only at the end, which is likely to give the opposite of the intended impression.  A good message would open with softening wording *before* stating the facts.

Comment: I agree with the comment above. It was the OP's mistake in the first place. The e-mail should start with an apologizing tone. If I were the customer, I would wonder why I should discard the previous quotation and why should I accept the new one.

Comment: @ChrisStratton it gives exactly the impression I would intend which is to make the facts instantly clear before the fluff. Also the sort of no nonsense email I'd prefer to get. It's just a mistake, not something to enter into a discourse about. Feel free to compose your own answer, quite possibly I'll upvote it

Comment: As you have now admitted was the intent, this is brusquely factual.  That may not raise offense in your business culture but it would mildly do so in many, for example in the US.  The awkward usage of English might partially excuse this by making it appear cross-cultural in origin.  But the impression will not be a positive one.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I deal with plenty of US people, but we don't have to agree. Many people like factual, personally if it's a mistake, just tell me, don't beat around the bush kissing me better. I'll survive. Would USA people really find this offensive? What on earth for? Ruin their day for some reason?